# My created root directory is not showing in my gallery in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

"I have fetch an image from ImageView and save it in root directory but when i go to pic the same image using from gallery , the created folder is not visible in gallery picker . but when i check the folder from file manager it show me the created folder with image",
    #I have used this code for saving the image in my directory.#

```
    public void saveImageToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap1) {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            if (sdCard != null) {
                File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/My_folder");
                if (directory.exists()) {
                    directory.delete();
                    Log.e("it run","directoty is exists");
                }
                directory.mkdirs();
                String strImageName = File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(directory, strImageName);
               // strFinalImage = file.getAbsolutePath();
                // Log.e(TAG + "strFinalImage22", strFinalImage + "");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bytes);
                    fileOutputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                      }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sd card mount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Intent code for gallery #
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    # OnActivityResultCode() #
     Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
                Log.e("Gallery", "File URI:" + imagePath);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
                cursor.close();
```

Comment: Switch your device off/on.

Comment: `in root directory` and `in my directory` and `sdcard` do not match with `getExternalStorageDirectory`.

Comment: `directory.delete();`. Why would you? You are not checking the return value.

Comment: `directory.mkdirs();`. You should only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist. Check the return value as it might fail.

Comment: have you taken write external storage permission

Comment: @greenapps . we are not save image for longtime. each time user create the new image the old one is deleted so i write the line   directory.delete();

Comment: @Narender Reddy Yes , i have taken.

Comment: @greenapps . means i should use public directories Like DCIM and Picture

Comment: Please react to the point to all my comments.